# Not allowing a player to move outside of a 2D grid Python 3

Tags: list, python-3.x, error-handling, 2d

I've come up with the following code which creates a grid and allows the user to move around.

```
choice_size = 8
board = []
x = choice_size
y = x
for row in range(0,x):
    board.append(["."]*y)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))
x = choice_size - 1
y = 0
while True:
    board[x][y] = "P"
    print_board(board)
    board[x][y] = "."
    right = ["right", "Right", "R", "r"]
    left = ["Left", "left", "L", "l"]
    up = ["Up", "up", "U", "u"]
    down = ["Down", "down", "D", "d"]
    direction_choice = input("Which direction would you like to move vertically (Up/Down)?")
    if direction_choice.strip() in up:
        movement_value = int(input("How far do you want to move up?"))
        x = x - movement_value
    elif direction_choice.strip() in down:
        movement_value = int(input("How far do you want to move down?"))
        x = x + movement_value
    else:
        print("Please ensure that you have chosen a valid option")
    direction_choice = input("Which direction would you like to move horizontally (Left/Right)?")
    if direction_choice.strip() in right:
        movement_value = int(input("How far do you want to move right?"))
        y = y + movement_value
    elif direction_choice.strip() in left:
        movement_value = int(input("How far do you want to move left?"))
        y = y - movement_value
    else:
        print("Please ensure that you have chosen a valid option")
```

When I enter a move which would take me out of the bottom of the grid, I get an error. And I still am able to move from the side of the board over to the other side (e.g If I move left off the edge of the board I will end up on the right side of the board).
I've experimented with Try/Except IndexError but I couldn't find any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Think about finding the position of the x and y coordinates within the list "board", and then compare this to the size of your board

Comment: So the Y coordinate would be the position of the sublist within "board" and the X coordinate would be the position inside that sublist?